# Elasticsearch fails to start with 'permissions read' error even though read permissions exist

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, security, java, elasticsearch

I have a symlink at `/etc/elasticsearch/analysis` that points to a mounted drive at `/elasticdata/fileshare/analysis` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Azure VM.  When I try and start elasticsearch I am getting the following permissions error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/etc/elasticsearch/analysis" "read")
```

The mounted drive has the following permissions:
`drwxrwxrwx 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 0 May 22 22:44 analysis`

The symlink has the following permissions:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch    43 May 22 22:49 analysis -> /elasticdata/fileshare/analysis/
```

TLDR: Symlink is owned by `elasticsearch` user and group with what seems to be read permissions, yet I still get read permission error on elasticsearch startup.

How can I resolve this permissions error?

Edit:

here are permissions for each step in the path:

```
/etc => drwxr-xr-x
/etc/elasticsearch => drwxr-S---
/etc/elasticsearch/analysis => lrwxrwxrwx
/elasticdata => drwxrwxrwx
/elasticdata/fileshare => drwxrwxrwx
/elasticdata/fileshare/analysis => drwxrwxrwx
```

Comment: can you share mount output for that partition with lsattr output on that dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify the permissions for each step in the path, as well es the destination of the symlink:

```
/etc
/etc/elasticsearch
/etc/elasticsearch/analysis
/elasticdata
/elasticdata/fileshare
/elasticdata/fileshare/analysis
```

Comment: see edit please

Comment: The permissions for `/etc/elasticsearch` are strange but would work if the owner is `elasticsearch`. Another possible cause my be something like AppArmor or something similar restricting access.

Comment: owner is indeed elasticsearch for `/etc/elasticsearch`. still no luck though